# Is the supply voltage made available anywhere on the Arduino Uno Board?

Tags: arduino-uno, power

I need to power an OpAmp based circuit that will be connected to my Arduino Uno input. Since I have a 12V adapter for the Arduino board, I want to draw power from it for this opamp(LM358).

Does anybody know if there is any way I can do this from the Arduino board(pins?)is as opposed to having to solder wires directly to the bottom of the DC jack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Vin` pin is available (next to `Gnd`) pins.

Comment: The voltage on Vin is after a protection diode. It will be around 0.7 V less than the supply voltage.